# Calculating the number of elements of a given order in a group of permutations.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $S$ denote the group of all those permutations of the English alphabet that fix the letters T, E, N, D, U, L, K, A, and R. Other letters may or may not be fixed. Show that $S$ has elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of order 36 and 39 respectively, but does not have any element of order 37 and 38.

My Attempt:=>*I found the no. of permutaions which fix the 9 elements in  $\{$ T, E, N, D, U, L, K, A, R $\}$, which is (26-9=17)!

**I consider the case when 1 element is fixed apart from the given fixed 9 elements, then 2 elements apart from first 10 and so on. These are 17!+16!+...+1!

From here, what should I do? I don't know.

Please help!

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem ?

Comment: @CaptainLama:Yeah,sorry I forget to consider this,I just focused on calculating elements by combinatorics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $S$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations on $26 - 9 = 17$ letters, its order is $17!$. Therefore it cannot contain an element of order $37$ or $38$, since neither of these numbers divide $17!$ (which is not divisible by any prime number greater than $17$).

To show that it contains elements of order $36$ and $39$: factor these numbers into coprime factors each less than $18$, and take disjoint cycles of the appropriate lengths.